# path_to_theme() goes to parent theme not subtheme

Tags: 7, theming, uri

I'm using zen as my parent theme and for some reason **path_to_theme()** is suddenly printing `/sites/all/themes/zen` instead of the subtheme `/sites/all/themes/<mytheme>`. What's even more confusing is that it's only happening when **node/12** is being displayed.

Could this code have something to do with it?

```
<?php
//template.php
if(isset($vars['node'])){
    if($vars['node']->nid == 12) {
        $vars['is_request_quote'] = true;
    }
}
?>
```

I use the variable `$is_request_quote` to change the layout in page.tpl.php. I do this through `<?php elseif( $is_request_quote ) : ?> -New layout here- <?php endif; ?>`.  Could that be the one affecting it?

Comment: Where do you call `path_to_theme()`?

Comment: Inside node--12.tpl.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer! It's probably not the best one so feel free to challenge. After several tests, I found out that `path_to_theme()` correctly points to the subtheme in **page.tpl.php** but when you use it in **node.tpl.php** it suddenly points to the parent theme (zen).

My answer is a 2 step process starting with creating the variable which stores the path I want:

```
function themename_preprocess(&$vars, $hook){
    $vars['THEMEPATH'] = base_path() . path_to_theme(); //points to subtheme
}
```

then to make sure it works in nodes, enable the following function to make it available in node.tpl.php. There doesn't need to be anything inside it, as long as the function gets declared in your `template.php` file.

```
function themename_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook){
    // Put anything here or leave it blank
}
```

After doing so, voila! You can now use $THEMEPATH in both nodes and pages.

Comment: Wouldn't work for me, not in html.tpl.php that is.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too. Solution [here](http://drupal.org/node/1151462#comment-4449312), applied to node instead of page, worked for me: copy `node.tpl.php` to your custom theme templates directory. Once I did that, `path_to_theme()` behaved correctly.